"Select All" Option Not Appearing as the First Item in TomSelect Dropdown
I'm using TomSelect to create a multi-select dropdown in my project. I've added a "Select All" option and I'm trying to ensure that it always appears as the first item in the dropdown. However, despite my efforts, the "Select All" option does not consistently appear at the top of the list.
Here's my current implementation:
function renderOptionItem(item, escape) {
  let img = item.src ? `<img class="me-2 tomselect-image" src="${escape(item.src)}" alt="icon" />` : '';
  let subtext = item.subtext ? `<div class="text-muted">${escape(item.subtext)}</div>` : '';
  return `<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        ${img}
        <div>
        <div>${escape(item.text)}</div>
        ${subtext}
        </div>
      </div>`;
}

function updateSelectedItemsLabel(tomSelectInstance) {
  const selectedItems = tomSelectInstance.getValue();
  const selectedCount = selectedItems.length;
  const control = tomSelectInstance.control.querySelector('.items');

  if (selectedCount > 3 && control) {
    // Clear the control and add the summary item
    control.innerHTML = `<div class="item">Valgt ${selectedCount} elementer</div>`;
  } else {
    tomSelectInstance.refreshItems(); // Refresh to show actual selected items
  }

  // Update the "Select all" checkbox state
  const selectAllCheckbox = tomSelectInstance.dropdown_content.querySelector('.option[data-value="select-all"] input[type="checkbox"]');
  if (selectAllCheckbox) {
    const allItemValues = Object.keys(tomSelectInstance.options).filter(value => value !== 'select-all');
    selectAllCheckbox.checked = selectedItems.length === allItemValues.length;

    // Set a specific ID to the checkbox
    selectAllCheckbox.id = 'groupSelect-opt-0'; // Replace 'your-specific-id' with the desired ID
  }
}

function handleSelectAll(tomSelectInstance) {
  const allItems = tomSelectInstance.options;
  const allItemValues = Object.keys(allItems).filter(value => value !== 'select-all');
  const selectedItems = tomSelectInstance.getValue();

  if (selectedItems.length === allItemValues.length) {
    tomSelectInstance.clear(); // Deselect all if already selected
  } else {
    tomSelectInstance.setValue(allItemValues); // Select all
  }
}

function moveSelectAllToTop(instance) {
  const dropdownContent = instance.dropdown_content;
  const selectAllOption = instance.getOption('select-all');
  if (selectAllOption) {
    dropdownContent.insertBefore(selectAllOption, dropdownContent.firstChild);
  }
}

function initializeTomSelect(selector, isSingleSelect = false) {
  const tomSelectInstance = new TomSelect(selector, {
    valueField: 'value',
    labelField: 'text',
    searchField: ['text', 'subtext'],
    render: {
      option: (item, escape) => {
        if (item.value === 'select-all') {
          return `<div class="d-flex align-items-center option" data-value="select-all">
                <div>Vælg alle</div>
              </div>`;
        } else {
          return renderOptionItem(item, escape);
        }
      },
      item: renderOptionItem
    },
    plugins: {
      'remove_button': {},
      'dropdown_input': {},
      'checkbox_options': {},
      'clear_button': {
        title: 'Ryd valgte' // Danish for "Clear selected"
      },
    },
    maxItems: isSingleSelect ? 1 : null,
    placeholder: isSingleSelect ? 'Vælg en mulighed...' : 'Vælg nogle muligheder...',
    create: false,
    allowEmptyOption: false, // Disallow empty options
    onInitialize: function() {
      if (isSingleSelect) {
        this.clear(); // Ensure no default selection
      }
      updateSelectedItemsLabel(this);

      // Add "Select all" option and ensure it's at the top
      this.addOption({ value: 'select-all', text: 'Vælg alle' });
      this.refreshOptions(false); // Refresh options immediately
      moveSelectAllToTop(this); // Ensure "Select all" is the first item

      // Add event listener for "Select all"
      this.dropdown_content.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const optionElement = event.target.closest('.option');
        if (optionElement && optionElement.getAttribute('data-value') === 'select-all') {
          event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the dropdown from closing
          handleSelectAll(this);
          updateSelectedItemsLabel(this);
        }
      });
    },
    onItemAdd: function(value) {
      if (value !== 'select-all') {
        updateSelectedItemsLabel(this);
      }
    },
    onItemRemove: function() {
      updateSelectedItemsLabel(this);
    },
    onDropdownOpen: function() {
      moveSelectAllToTop(this);
    },
    onOptionAdd: function() {
      moveSelectAllToTop(this);
    }
  });

  // Handle the clear button functionality
  tomSelectInstance.on('clear', function() {
    tomSelectInstance.refreshItems();
  });

  // Handle changes to re-enable item removal if more than 3 selected
  tomSelectInstance.on('change', function() {
    const selectedItems = tomSelectInstance.getValue();
    const control = tomSelectInstance.control.querySelector('.items');

    if (selectedItems.length <= 3 && control && control.innerHTML.includes('elementer')) {
      tomSelectInstance.refreshItems(); // Refresh to show actual selected items
    }

    // Update the "Select all" checkbox state
    const selectAllCheckbox = tomSelectInstance.dropdown_content.querySelector('.option[data-value="select-all"] input[type="checkbox"]');
    if (selectAllCheckbox) {
      const allItemValues = Object.keys(tomSelectInstance.options).filter(value => value !== 'select-all');
      selectAllCheckbox.checked = selectedItems.length === allItemValues.length;
    }
  });
}

// Initialize Tom Select elements
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  initializeTomSelect('#employeeSelect');
  initializeTomSelect('#entryTypeSelect', true); // Set isSingleSelect to true for entryTypeSelect
});

Rendered code from developer tools
<div class="mb-3" id="groupSelectContainer">
  <label for="groupSelect-ts-control" class="form-label specificLabel" id="groupSelect-ts-label">Afdeling</label>
  
  <select id="groupSelect" class="tom-select-simple tomselected ts-hidden-accessible" autocomplete="off" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Vælg nogle muligheder..." tabindex="-1">
    <option value="" disabled="" hidden="">Vælg nogle muligheder...</option>
    <option value="23">Bartenders</option>
    <option value="34">IT_Department</option>
    <option value="20">Kitchen</option>
    <option value="24">Reception_and_Reservations</option>
    <option value="37">Top_Management</option>
    <option value="22">Waitstaff</option>
  </select>
  
  <div class="ts-wrapper tom-select-simple multi plugin-remove_button plugin-dropdown_input plugin-checkbox_options plugin-clear_button focus input-active dropdown-active">
    <div class="ts-control" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="groupSelect-ts-dropdown" id="groupSelect-ts-control" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="groupSelect-opt-2">
      <input class="items-placeholder" tabindex="-1" placeholder="Vælg nogle muligheder...">
      <div class="clear-button" title="Ryd valgte">⨯</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="ts-dropdown multi plugin-remove_button plugin-dropdown_input plugin-checkbox_options plugin-clear_button" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
      <div class="dropdown-input-wrap">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" size="1" tabindex="-1" class="dropdown-input" placeholder="Vælg nogle muligheder...">
      </div>
      
      <div role="listbox" tabindex="-1" class="ts-dropdown-content" id="groupSelect-ts-dropdown">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center option" data-selectable="" data-value="23" role="option" id="groupSelect-opt-1">
          <input class="tomselect-checkbox" type="checkbox">
          <div>
            <div>Bartenders</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center option" data-value="select-all" data-selectable="" role="option" id="groupSelect-opt-1">
          <input class="tomselect-checkbox" type="checkbox">
          <div>Vælg alle</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center option active" data-selectable="" data-value="34" role="option" id="groupSelect-opt-2" aria-selected="true">
          <input class="tomselect-checkbox" type="checkbox">
          <div>
            <div>IT_Department</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center option" data-selectable="" data-value="20" role="option" id="groupSelect-opt-3">
          <input class="tomselect-checkbox" type="checkbox">
          <div>
            <div>Kitchen</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center option" data-selectable="" data-value="24" role="option" id="groupSelect-opt-4">
          <input class="tomselect-checkbox" type="checkbox">
          <div>
            <div>Reception_and_Reservations</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center option" data-selectable="" data-value="37" role="option" id="groupSelect-opt-5">
          <input class="tomselect-checkbox" type="checkbox">
          <div>
            <div>Top_Management</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center option" data-selectable="" data-value="22" role="option" id="groupSelect-opt-6">
          <input class="tomselect-checkbox" type="checkbox">
          <div>
            <div>Waitstaff</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

The Issue
Despite the code snippet above, the "Select All" option does not always appear as the first item in the dropdown. I've tried the following approaches:

Adding the "Select All" option first using this.addOption.
Manually moving the "Select All" option to the top using
insertBefore.

However, these methods do not consistently result in the "Select All" option being at the top.
Expected Behavior
The "Select All" option should consistently appear as the first item in the dropdown list whenever the dropdown is opened.
Request for Help
I'm looking for guidance on how to ensure the "Select All" option always appears at the top of the dropdown list. Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Is your "Vælg nogle muligheder..." "Choose some options" your Select All here?  Perhaps put up a runnable snippet if possible Also you have invalid HTML here with a duplicate id in id="groupSelect-opt-1" which will never work properly

Please keep in mind that using AI is not permitted on Stack Overflow, even to reword/rewrite your own questions. Thanks!

No, it is the "Vælg alle" thats in :


Vælg alle


@Mark Schultheiss I was pointing out the issue with the double groupSelect-opt-1 as a comment to a prior post in this thread that must have been deleted .. the id is set by the tom select API dynamically, and I have not been able to find a solution to i.e. change the id of "Vælg alle" (Select all) to groupSelect-opt-0

Just for clarity you CANNOT have duplicate ids in an HTML document such as id="groupSelect-opt-1".  An ID is unique within the entire DOM per the HTML specification ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id  IF that library is doing this, that is a flaw/bug in that library.
